# Erorrvoley org.json.JSONException: Value of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I have my project in registration to web service with JSON object in response.

This is the registration class:

```
public class RegisterReq extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog pDialogreg;
Button register;
EditText tx_username,tx_password,
        tx_nama,tx_alamat,
        tx_telepon,tx_email,
        tx_no_ktp, tx_confirm_pass;
Intent intent;
int success;
ConnectivityManager conMgr;
private SessionManager session;

private static final String TAG = RegisterReq.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "massage";
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_req);
    pDialogreg = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialogreg.setCancelable(false);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    tx_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    tx_password =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tx_confirm_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);
    tx_nama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama);
    tx_alamat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alamat);
    tx_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    tx_telepon=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.telepon);
    tx_no_ktp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.no_ktp);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String username = tx_username.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = tx_password.getText().toString().trim();
            String confirm_password = tx_confirm_pass.getText().toString().trim();
            String nama = tx_nama.getText().toString().trim();
            String alamat =tx_alamat.getText().toString().trim();
            String telepon = tx_telepon.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = tx_email.getText().toString().trim();
            String no_ktp = tx_no_ktp.getText().toString().trim();

            if(password.equals(confirm_password) ){
                checkRegister(username, password, nama, alamat, telepon, email, no_ktp );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password not Match with Confirm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterReq.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}

private void checkRegister(final String username,
                           final String password,
                           final String nama,
                           final String alamat,
                           final String telepon,
                           final String email,
                           final String no_ktp
) {

    pDialogreg.setMessage("Register ...");
    showDialog();
    String url ="http://gis.sigjalan.com/web-services-db.php?flag=fAddUser&username="+username+
            "&password="+password+
            "&nama="+nama+
            "&alamat="+alamat+
            "&telepon="+telepon+
            "&email="+email+
            "&no_ktp="+no_ktp;
    JsonArrayRequest strReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            String result = response.toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray Jarray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity( new Intent(RegisterReq.this,MainActivity.class));

                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


    },
            //untuk error
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Erorrvoley " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "error voley"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialogreg.isShowing())
        pDialogreg.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialogreg.isShowing())
        pDialogreg.dismiss();
}}
```

This is the activity file of registration form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.gun21.gunawan.gispro.RegisterReq">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:orientation="vertical"
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/register_req_form" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:orientation="vertical">

        <View android:id="@+id/View1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#448AFF" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="30dip" android:textColor="#C0392B" android:text="REGISTER BELOW" android:textSize="16dip"
        />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/username" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Username" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:singleLine="true"
          />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Password" android:password="true" android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/confirm_password" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Comfirmation Password" android:password="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/nama" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Nama" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/alamat" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Alamat" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/telepon" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Telepon" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText android:id="@+id/no_ktp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:hint="No KTP" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_register" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" android:background="#2980B9" android:textColor="#fff"
          android:text="Register" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the response:

```
{
  "id_user_pemilik_kos": 73
}
```

and this is the error:

> 05 - 26 03: 04: 49.513 30080 - 30080 / com.gun21.gunawan.gispro E / RegisterReq: Erorrvoley org.json.JSONException: Value {
>         "id_user_pemilik_kos": 74
>       } of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

I don't know what is the problem so, what can be done to solve this problem ?

Comment: The error message is let you know that "JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray". Please check your data response 

Can you share full data response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the service that lives at the requested URL is returning a single JSON object, and not an array of JSON objects.

Try changing your `strReq` from a `JsonArrayRequest` to a `JsonObjectRequest`. That means the `onResponse` function will accept a `JSONObject` parameter instead of a `JSONArray`.

```
JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // ...
        // Note: you will likely not need this conversion to a JSONObject anymore
        // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); <-- Not needed now
    }
}
```

I believe [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) will help explain the difference between JsonArrayRequest and JsonObjectRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    }
}
```

You have given that you will get an JsonArray from response. In `onResponse()` method's body you have used JsonObject. You have mixed up.